# Object(…) is not a function at Function.DominoAdapter.makeCurrent in angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-universal

I am facing above issue after serving npm with ssr for angular universal

exact error is this

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Function.DominoAdapter.makeCurrent (D:\1Code\1Projects\anguProj\sampledata - Copy (2)\dist\server.js:172102:83)
    at D:\1Code\1Projects\anguProj\sampledata - Copy (2)\dist\server.js:172824:23
    at D:\1Code\1Projects\anguProj\sampledata - Copy (2)\dist\server.js:30866:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at createPlatform (D:\1Code\1Projects\anguProj\sampledata - Copy (2)\dist\server.js:30866:15)
    at D:\1Code\1Projects\anguProj\sampledata - Copy (2)\dist\server.js:30887:17
    at D:\1Code\1Projects\anguProj\sampledata - Copy (2)\dist\server.js:30883:17
    at _getPlatform (D:\1Code\1Projects\anguProj\sampledata - Copy (2)\dist\server.js:172931:12)
    at renderModuleFactory (D:\1Code\1Projects\anguProj\sampledata - Copy (2)\dist\server.js:173020:20)
    at CommonEngine.<anonymous> (D:\1Code\1Projects\anguProj\sampledata - Copy (2)\dist\server.js:253198:131)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
    import 'reflect-metadata';

    import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

    import * as express from 'express';
    import { join } from 'path';

    // Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
    enableProdMode();

    // Express server
    const app = express();

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
    const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

    // * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
    const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

    // Express Engine
    import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
    // Import module map for lazy loading
    import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

    app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
      providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
      ]
    }));

    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

    // TODO: implement data requests securely
    app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
      res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
    });

    // Server static files from /browser
    app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

    // All regular routes use the Universal engine
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.render('index', { req });
    });

    // Start up the Node server
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });
```

Comment: Is it an actual answer or an edit to your question?